# Failed to create cloud account while adding an Object Storage Service

Tags: storage, ibm-cloud

I am Trying to create a new free Object Storage Service for testing - and I am getting error:

> Service broker error: `{"description"=>"Failed to create cloud account."}`

I have other Bluxmix services created, and can remove/create other services.
I am only receiving this error while trying to add the IBM Object Storage

Answer (score 1):

The object storage service has some issue. You can see the service's status on status page here: http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus

You can also be alerted of any notifications by subscribing to the RSS feed for the Bluemix Status page. This approach provides a way for you to get updates without having to regularly consult the status page.

Use the Support Widget to open a ticket. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error with Object Storage. I contacted Bluemix support and they told me this error was occurring because "my name had raised a false flag against the U.S. debarred parties list." They said this is very rare, and the only way to fix the problem is to contact support with a request.

To contact support:

- Login to Bluemix
- Open the account tray by clicking the avatar in the top right
- Click “Get Help”
- Click “Get In Touch”

I'm now able to provision Object Storage.